# Using Channels in Go to receive Responses and Write to SQL Concurrently

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am working with Go to implement a pipeline of JSON data from an external API, process the message and then send to a SQL database.

I am trying to concurrently run API requests, then after I return a response, I'd like to send it to be inserted into the DB via another goroutine via `load()`.

In my below code, sometimes I'll receive my `log.Printf()` in the `load()` func, other times I won't. Which indicates that I'm likely closing a channel or not properly setting up the communication.

The pattern I am attempting is something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Request struct {
    url string
}

type Response struct {
    status  int
    args    Args    `json:"args"`
    headers Headers `json:"headers"`
    origin  string  `json:"origin"`
    url     string  `json:"url"`
}

type Args struct {
}

type Headers struct {
    accept string `json:"Accept"`
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    numRequests := 5
    responses := make(chan Response, 5)
    defer close(responses)
    for i := 0; i < numRequests; i++ {
        req := Request{url: "https://httpbin.org/get"}
        go func(req *Request) {
            resp, err := extract(req)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error extracting data from API")
                return
            }
            // Send response to channel
            responses <- resp
        }(&req)

        // Perform go routine to load data
        go load(responses)
    }

    log.Println("Execution time: ", time.Since(start))
}

func extract(req *Request) (r Response, err error) {
    var resp Response
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", req.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    request.Header = http.Header{
        "accept": {"application/json"},
    }

    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error")
        return resp, err
    }
    // Read response data
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error")
        return resp, err
    }
    json.Unmarshal(body, &resp)
    resp.status = response.StatusCode

    return resp, nil
}

type Record struct {
    origin string
    url    string
}

func load(ch chan Response) {

    // Read response from channel
    resp := <-ch

    // Process the response data
    records := process(resp)
    log.Printf("%+v\n", records)

    // Load data to db stuff here

}

func process(resp Response) (record Record) {
    // Process the response struct as needed to get a record of data to insert to DB
    return record
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program has no protection against completion before the work is done. So sometimes the program terminates before the goroutine can finish.

To prevent that, use a WaitGroup:

```
   wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
   for i := 0; i < numRequests; i++ {
     ...
     wg.Add(1)
     go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        load(responses)
     }()
   }
  wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used these a little bit and understand the basics of them. Now I guess my bigger question is how do I synchronize results that come in from the API, then send them over through a receiving channel to process for a db insert? I'm not seeing the way to synchronize the two streams of data in and out.

Comment: @Coldchain9 the way to syncronize the data in and data out would be to remove the concurrency altogether. Maybe you can clarify what exactly you're after?

Comment: @Adrian The idea would be like a FIFO queue. Where when a response is received from the API and deserialized, it is then sent to a queue which will send the data to the DB. As the DB Queue gets an item, it will insert them on arrival.